# How can I make this more efficient? (Merging arrays in C)

Tags: c, arrays, performance

The program is supposed to merge two arrays and place them in an output array. What I have is:

```
void Merge(int *arr1, int *arr2, int *output, int arr1size, int arr2size) { 
   int arr2count = 0, arr1count = 0;                                        
   while (arr1count < arr1size) {                                           
      if (arr2count >= arr2size) {   /* dump arr1 because arr2 is done */                                         
         *output++ = *arr1++;                                               
         arr1count++;                                                       
      }                                                                     
      else if (*arr1 < *arr2) {                                             
         *output++ = *arr1++;                                               
         arr1count++;                                                       
      }                                                                     
      else {                                                                
         *output++ = *arr2++;                                               
         arr2count++;                                                       
      }                                                                     
   }                                                                        
   while (arr2count++ < arr2size) {    /* dump arr2 */                                     
      *output++ = *arr2++;                                                  
   }                                                                        
}
```

How can I make this more efficient? I mean, strip literally any bit of code off to make it slightly more efficient.

For arguement's sake, consider the triple while loop implementation (shown below) less efficient.

```
while (arr1count < arr1size && arr2count < arr2size) { .... }
while (arr1count < arr1size) { .... }
while (arr2count < arr2size) { .... }
```

Also, this must use pointer notation, not array notation (I wish...)

Comment: What do you mean with “this must use pointer notation?” What does that mean and where does the restriction come from? For better performance, consider throwing in a `restrict` to let the compiler know that `arr1`, `arr2`, and `output` do not overlap.

Comment: All other attempts to optimize this code heavily depend on the range of data you expect, the compiler you use and the platform this is supposed to run on.

Comment: By pointer notation, I mean don't use brackets to index the spots in the arrays. So instead of:

    for (i=0; i < arr1size+arr2size; i++) { 
       output[i] = arr[j];
   }
(for example), using pointer notation as above.

That's the only restriction. This is for an online (non-graded) course I'm participating in, and that was a requirement.

Comment: And why can't you use that notation? Any other restrictions I should be aware of? What compiler and what platform are you programming against? Please try to answer the questions in my second comment, too.

Comment: I'm unaware of the compiler. It's a web-based platform that compiles and runs the code.

Comment: In this case, I cannot help you. There are not enough known parameters to be able to optimize this. Any decent compiler would be able to optimize the second variant better (less conditional expressions to evaluate), so something smells fishy. For some more generic help, try the second variant and change the second two `while` loops to `memcpy` calls as `memcpy` is typically well-optimized even on shitty platforms.

Comment: Could you provide sample inputs and outputs please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried removing variables and increments. Note these are *minor* improvements while the algorithm still takes O(m+n) time.

Edit: incorporated the breaking of loop as mentioned by user2048454

Edit2: Removed two while loops and replaced with `memcpy`.Thanks to FUZxxl

```
void Merge2(int *arr1, int *arr2, int *output, int *a1last, int *a2last) { 
   while (arr1 < a1last && arr2 < a2last) {
      if (*arr1 < *arr2) {                                             
         *output++ = *arr1++;                                                
      }                                                                     
      else {                                                                
         *output++ = *arr2++;                                               
      }                                                                     
   }                  
   /* Replaced while with memcpy () */
   memcpy(output,arr1,sizeof(int)*(a1last-arr1));
   memcpy(output,arr2,sizeof(int)*(a2last-arr2));                                                  
   }                                                                        
}

int main()
{
    int a[]={1,3,5,7};
    int b[]={2,4,6,8};
    int c[10];
    int i;
    Merge2(a,b,c,&a[4],&b[4]); //&a[4] points to the end address of the array. Do not access value at that address, it is "out of bounds"

    for(i=0; i<8; i++)
        printf("%d ",c[i]);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any efficiency gained is better than nothing. Thanks for your input! I never thought to use memcpy().

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
void Merge(int *arr1, int *arr2, int *output, int arr1size, int arr2size) {
  for (int i=0,i1=0,i2=0; i<arr1size+arr2size; i++) {
    if      (i1==arr1size) *output++ = *arr2++;
    else if (i2==arr2size) *output++ = *arr1++;
    else if (*arr1<*arr2)  *output++ = *arr1++, i1++;
    else                   *output++ = *arr2++, i2++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the above code, the arrays are initially sorted and output should also contain sorted values.

One idea because of the restriction you mention would be to not use arr1count/arr2count, and use instead:
arr1last/arr2last

where:

"arr1last=arr1+arr1size" and "arr2last=arr2+arr2size"

this way you won't have to increment a counter and the compiler will juggle with fewer variables(--*count --*size ++*last) just do the compare on arr1 < arr1last. same for arr2

Also your first if when true, will always be true, so depending on the size of your arrays it might be worth breaking out at that point and going with the triple loop implementation you've mentioned, because the above 2 loop implementation might be inefficient if arr2size=1, arr1size=999 and arr2[0] would be among the first values in 'output'